# how do I incorporate custom format into TEXT function in excel

Tags: excel, string, text, excel-formula, format

I'm using the custom format: Tough (#,##0")";"Delicate ("-#,##0")"

Is there a way of combining the above custom format with the TEXT function so I can concatenate the formatted text into a longer string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot use your custom format as written in your question -- returns an error about being an invalid format.

But to use it in the `TEXT` function, you need to *escape* the included quotes with another quote.

Assuming your custom format is really:  `"Tough "(#,##0);"Delicate "(-#,##0)`

Then you can use:

```
=TEXT(A1,"""Tough ""(#,##0);""Delicate ""(-#,##0)")
```

in the `TEXT` function

Comment: Yeah the leading " got removed when I copy and pasted it onto a cell to try and copy it in the TEXT formula. Your answer works. Thank you.